# Failed to load resource jQuery function after published

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, jsonresult

In Visual Studio 2012, I'm using MVC 4 and C#. I have three `dropdownlist`s. Each is based on and related to another with binding and that works fine, but after I published, it has not worked because I have a jquery function to read data from `jsonresult` and it doesn't allow access to the function `options.url = "/invoice/GETCompanyByID";`.

```
if ($("#Area").val() != "Please select") {
    var options = {};
    options.url = "/invoice/GETCompanyByID";
    options.type = "POST";   
    options.data = JSON.stringify({ stateid: $("#Area").val() });     
    options.dataType = "json";
    options.contentType = "application/json";
    options.success = function (states) { 
        $("#state").empty();
        $("#inv").empty();
        for (var i = 0; i <= states.length; i++)
        {                         
            $("#state").append("<option selected value=" + states[i].Value + ">" + states[i].Text + "</option>")
            $("#contract").val($("#state").val())
            $("#state").prop("disabled", false);
        }
    };
    options.error = function () { alert("Error retrieving states!"); };
    $.ajax(options);
}
else {
    $("#state").empty();
    $("#state").prop("disabled", true);
}

$("#areaid").val($("#Area").val())
});
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GETCompanyByID(int stateid)
{
    return Json(new SelectList(DAL.Get_All_Contract(stateid), "IDContract", "ContractNo"));
}
```

Comment: XHR failed loading: POST "http://192.168.191.4/invoice/GETCompanyByID".

Comment: what was the actual error when it failed? What status code, and what message?

Comment: Why are you using POST when you could have used GET request? And also, what is the error message you are getting from that request?

Comment: i using post method  and finally i solved my error which was came from             options.url = "/invoice/GETCompanyByID";
and i should to use Url.contant("~/invoice/GETCompanyByID")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved my error which came from

```
options.url = "/invoice/GETCompanyByID";
```

while I should use

```
Url.content("~/invoice/GETCompanyByID")
```

Comment: You're sure that it is `Url.contant`, not maybe `Url.content`?